# How can I get zeros or ones instead of True or false using pd.get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working as a beginner on the dataset of Titanic survivals, and I am trying to convert the **Sex column** into a single column with **zeros** and **ones** using **get_dummies**.

```
   female   male
0    True  False
1   False   True
2    True  False
```

My problem is **instead of getting** 0s and 1s, I get True/False.

Any assistance, please?

This is the line of coding that I used in Python:

```
male = pd.get_dummies(training_set['Sex'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `dtype` parameter to [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

> **dtype**: dtype, default bool
>
> Data type for new columns. Only a single dtype is allowed.

```
pd.get_dummies(training_set['Sex'], dtype=int)
```

###### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['female', 'male', 'female']})

out = pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], dtype=int)
```

Output:

```
   female  male
0       1     0
1       0     1
2       1     0
```

Some valid dtypes (non-exhaustive):

```
# pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], dtype=bool) # default
   female   male
0    True  False
1   False   True
2    True  False

# pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], dtype=int)
   female  male
0       1     0
1       0     1
2       1     0

# pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], dtype=float)
   female  male
0     1.0   0.0
1     0.0   1.0
2     1.0   0.0

# pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], dtype=str)
  female male
0      1     
1           1
2      1
```

Comment: @SH_IQ you're welcome, could you please edit your question to remove the images and use a minimal example as text instead? That would be more accessible for future readers.

Comment: ok, dear sir. I will remove them